# Batch Class to count the number of record with same Name

Tags: apex, soql, batch

I need to write the batch class Where I need to store count of duplicate value of field

Requirement - On Account Object there is one field called Parent_Name__c which is text Field its store the Parent Account Name.

Also on Account we have another field Called Count__c which is number Field, So Suppose if Parent account name is same on multiple accounts, I need to get the count and store in the field called Count__c.

For Example-

Account 1
Parent Name = Test and

Account 2
Parent Name = Test

so the count should be 2 and its should be store in the field Count__c.

Comment: Why a batch class? why not a summary report if urgent...

Comment: This site is not a free coding service. If you don't know how to do this and can't afford the time to learn, then you should hire a consultant or contractor to aid you.

Comment: Hi Derek, i have tried with the code but its not working that's y am looking for the help if you want the code i write  i can also paste that

Comment: Yes, if you're asking for help with code, and have written some code already _then you should always share what you currently have tried_. A list of requirements with no code is a "do my work for me" request rather than a request for help in overcoming a specific issue. You should also point out a _specific thing you're having issues with_. "Help me write this class" is too broad. "How do I get a query to count duplicated values? Here is what I've tried..." would be a much more targeted (and thus better) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you're trying to write should look something like the following. I've written an article about this some time ago, which I call the [Aggregate-Query-Update pattern](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html). It's the standard design pattern you should learn how to use, as almost all trigger and batch logic ends up looking like this.

```
public class UpdateParentNameCountBatch implements Database.Batchable<Account> {
  public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Parent_Name__c FROM Account]);
  }
  public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Account[] scope) {
    // Initialize parent name to count map
    Map<String, Integer> countByName = new Map<String, Integer>();
    // Aggregate data for our query
    for(Account record: scope) {
      countByName.put(record.Parent_Name__c, 0);
    }
    // Skip nulls for now
    countByName.remove(null);
    // Query records for matching duplicates
    for(AggregateResult result: [SELECT COUNT(Id) sum, Parent_Name__c parentName FROM Account WHERE Parent_Name__c = :countByName.keySet() GROUP BY parent_Name__c]) {
      countByName.put((String)result.get('parentName'), (Integer)result.get('sum'));
    }
    // null out the Count__c field for records with no parent
    countByName.put(null, null);
    // Update the Count__c field
    for(Account record: scope) {
      record.Count__c = countByName.get(record.Parent_Name__c);
    }
    update scope;
  }
  public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
  }
}
```

This is intentionally unoptimized code, so I would not recommend putting it directly in production.